# Tiny sort add numbering to the sorted elements

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have been researching to find a way to add number to sorted list returned by the Tinysort jquery add-on

So what I want is a way to add attribute `data-id` in incrementing order or a class in incrementing order like box1,box2 after the sort has completed

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mba4c/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked and modified the plugin to handle this internally.

All you have to do is pass `dataIndex: true` in the options. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/2mxm5ny6/1/).

It renders the following HTML:

```
<div id="div1" data-index="0">1</div>
<div id="div2" data-index="1">2</div>
<div id="div4" data-index="2">4</div>
```

You can download the modified plugin from [here](https://github.com/mrchief/TinySort/blob/master/src/jquery.tinysort.js). I'm going to send a pull request to the author and see if he/she entertains this idea.

Answer (score 0):

After the elements have been sorted, you can loop them and add a class or an attribute with an increasing number.

You can use:

```
$( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
 $(this).addClass("box"+(index+1));//This to add class
 $(this).attr("data-id",(index+1));//This to add attribute
});
```

PS. `index` starts at 0. So if you want your class/attribute to start from 1 you have to use `index+1`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mba4c/73/)

Comment: I like this to happen by inbuilt function/callback as I am using json and handlers to add data